# SeekBar not working properly with streaming audio from server

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-seekbar

I have audio files on my mysql server. When audio is played seekbar mismatch with current position and repeat audio in background with difference of milliseconds. When I remove seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration) it works fine. And in Android:7 audio not playing properly. Please help me to solve this problem as soon as possible. Thank You in Advance.

```
  initilizeUI();

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if (b && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.seekTo((mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * i);
                Log.d("time", String.valueOf((mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * seekBar.getProgress()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    return root;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void initilizeUI() {
    btn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    seekBar.setMax(99);
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(R.drawable.restartbtn), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        btn.setImageResource(id);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton) {

        try {

            mPlayer.setDataSource(audio_url);
            mPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(audio_url);
            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
            btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebtn);
        } else {
            mPlayer.pause();
            btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbtn);
        }

        seekUpdation();
    }
}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekUpdation();
    }
};

public void seekUpdation() {
    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        seekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mPlayer
                .getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100));
                   seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem might be the audio file itself (not the code). Download `MediaInfo` and check your file with it. Or test with a 44100hz stereo MP3 with a Contant bitrate (CBR) not Variable bitrate (VBR). You could also share a link to one of these mysterious _"audio files on my mysql server."_ for our own checking.

Comment: Please check above link and how to download 'MediaInfo' ?

Comment: I've checked your file and it is VBR which can be problematic for seeking. See if my answer helps you. PS: Here's the link to [download MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) for your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your MP3 file and yes it is encoded in **V**ariable **B**it-**R**ate mode.

**Possible solutions**:

**(1)** Confirm if working: The [CBR version of your MP3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/of95cobfghykmrv/posh_sukal_cbr.mp3?dl=1) (right-click and save, then put & test on your server). If seekbar is working as expected then your solution is to re-convert. You can use a tool to re-convert MP3 from VBR mode into CBR mode.

Try converting via this site : https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp3

If converting many files try : [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) which runs on the commandline, can process multiple files in a folder.

**(2)** Your values from `.getDuration()` and `.getCurrentPosition()` must be **divided by 1000**.

`.getDuration()` will return a number in milliseconds. It takes 1000 m-secs to make 1 second. So your code must get expected value by dividing. *eg:* 5000 ms / 1000 = 5 seconds duration.

*examples:*

```
//# when using "getDuration"...
seekBar.setMax( mPlayer.getDuration() / 1000 );

//# when using "getCurrentPosition"...
seekBar.setProgress( mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 );
```

Comment: Still not working in many devices ,seekbar not taking duration of audio and seekbar progress set at last.

Comment: See if the newly added point **(2)** helps you.

Comment: mPlayer.getDuration() returns 0.

Comment: I think it's because your file isn't even loaded (or at least the metadata is not ready) when you try to get duration. Is your code from a tutorial about playing a file on device storage? Such a file is immediately available to get duration from but not when the web is still sending small packets of the file. Try to listen for a metadata loaded event.

Comment: I think , when I tested it with raw file it works fine and even in latest version it works with web url but not in all devices. Can you please help me for this.

Comment: I edited my code. Please check it in above question